# Android ActivityRecognitionService.java Not Starting - Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I have the following code in one class Pinger.java

```
public class Pinger extends Service implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    // start the API for recognition
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
    // other code here

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Intent acr_intent = new Intent(this, ActivityRecognitionService.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, acr_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 0, pIntent);
    }
}
```

My ActivityRecognitionService.java looks like this:
public class ActivityRecognitionService extends IntentService {

```
private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

public ActivityRecognitionService() {
    super("My Activity Recognition Service");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
        Log.i("AR", getType(result.getMostProbableActivity().getType()) + "t" + result.getMostProbableActivity().getConfidence());
        Intent i = new Intent("com.xyz.xyz.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION_DATA");
        i.putExtra("Activity", getType(result.getMostProbableActivity().getType()));
        i.putExtra("Confidence", result.getMostProbableActivity().getConfidence());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Broadcast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}

private String getType(int type) {
    if (type == DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN)
        return "Unknown";
    else if (type == DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
        return "In Vehicle";
    else if (type == DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE)
        return "On Bicycle";
    else if (type == DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT)
        return "On Foot";
    else if (type == DetectedActivity.STILL)
        return "Still";
    else if (type == DetectedActivity.TILTING)
        return "Tilting";
    else
        return "";
}
```

In the ActivityRecognitionService.java, it seems that the Toast for "Broadcast" is not showing up, I'm trying to understand why not looking at the log file also seems like the ActivityRecognitionService.java is not being called by Pinger.java. Please advise, I'm trying to figure out once I can do this, then I think I can read the Activity from a Broadcast service I have set up.

Comment: "seems that the Toast for "Broadcast" is not showing up" - you may not be on the main thread. Check with the debugger or dispatch the show() call to a main thread via a static Handler.

Comment: Is your service registered in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yup, I have it declared as "<service android:enabled="true" android:name="ActivityRecognitionService"></service>" and <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>

Comment: Can you confirm requestActivityUpdates is returning a success?

Comment: It appears to be called as in the Toast comes back saying its connected, but it doesn't show that ActivityRecognitionService is running in any of the logs.

Comment: So looks like I got it working - however, now it freezes for whatever reason. Guess I'll open a new question then.